# Execute same testsuite in parallel using Junit5

Tags: junit5, parallel-execution

In Junit 5, we can achieve parallel execution by specifying in junit-platform.properties file.
Also we can run the same testsuite multiple times by using @TestTemplate but this is sequential run.

Is there a way to combine both approaches.

I want to execute the same testsuite on multiple browsers parallelly.

When the testsuite execution start, the first test should be picked and run on all the available browsers. and so on.

I am using selenium Junit combination to write the UI testcases.